# Help me to make a algorithm to determine the Rank of a Matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, console, matrix, rank

I want to make a program which will determine the [Rank of a given Matrix](http://goo.gl/vFCYa) in C# Console Application. But I cannot able to make the algorithm for that. Can you please help me make that algorithm?

Comment: Wikipedia lists and links to a bunch of methods. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I can make it manually using Gaussian elimination method. But I can't to implement this in my program. Please help.

Comment: Wikipedia link for Gaussian elimination is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_elimination_method

Comment: Not without use of thy brain tissue, shalt thou gain understanding of the magic of rank.

Comment: @Mau: Can you please able to make the code for me?

Comment: @chanchal1987: Exactly what I suspected. Cheque or cash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the basic Gauss elimination method. Counting the number of non-zero rows will give you the rank. But this method is not really numerically robust. As the wikipedia article says, there are a few other algorithms, such as singular value decomposition (SVD)or QR decomposition with pivoting. For both, you should easily be able to find basic implementations.

But working with accurate numbers as you need for this, you always have to think about the numerical inaccuracies of the IEEE representation of floats in the computer. 
Read more about it on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: But I cannot able to understand how many iteration will be calculate to determine my answer.

Comment: From where can I find other algorithms(SVD, QRD, etc.)?